# After page refresh for Server Side Event in svelte file, the page is showing the page "can't be found" error

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have server side event page. The code is simple:

```
<script>


import { onMount } from "svelte";

let streamingnow = ""
let datafromserver
$: documentkey = ""
let audiofile = ""

    const source = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/sse');

    source.addEventListener('message', message => {
        
        // if there is a message from the server. Play the audio
        if (message) {         
            audiofile.play()
        }

        //order data from server 
        streamingnow = message.data
        
        datafromserver = JSON.parse(streamingnow)
        documentkey = datafromserver.documentKey._id
           
    })

</script>
```

Here is my HTML to display an audio every message I receive from the server:

```
<main>


<audio id="playit" bind:this={audiofile} controls>
  <source src="./sound/bensound-dance.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    //adding track kind caption is for a11 compliance.
    <track src="  " kind="captions" srclang="en" label="english_captions">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<h1>SSE Messages</h1>
  
<h1>Order Id : {documentkey}</h1>
   
</main>
```

I'm receiving notification from the server, so the sse is working fine.
The issue I'm facing is when the page is refreshed, the page shows "page can't be found" and the url is showing the correct address. Upon searching online, I read about how the connection can be re-established by not refreshing the page. It's for asp question but I'm wondering how to do that in svelte?

Do I need to create onMount fn or something to re-establish the connection or a button with onclick event?

How to recreate/re-establish the connection -on refresh- without user input?

Comment: Try move JS into `onMount` or move the `<source>` element into a `{#if browser}` block. Looks like there is a 404 error on something while server sided rendering is happening